# Google Maps JS Embed Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, safari

I have built a quick website with some embedded maps and custom markers. It works fine on my PC desktop in Chrome and works on my Google Pixel fine, but when I check it on my Mac in Safari/iPhone it does not display or render the map (works in Chrome).

Below is a sample of the code:

```
<div id="oakville-map" class="row map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
    //Maps          
    var iconBase = '/pathtomarker/markers/red_circle_';
    var icons = {
        one: {
            icon: iconBase + '1.png'
        },
        two: {
            icon: iconBase + '2.png'
        },
        three: {
            icon: iconBase + '3.png'
        },
        four: {
            icon: iconBase + '4.png'
        },
        five: {
            icon: iconBase + '5.png'
        },
        six: {
            icon: iconBase + '6.png'
        }
    };

    var element =  document.getElementById('oakville-map');
    if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
    {
        //Oakville Map
        function initMap() {
            var tmhOakville = {lat: 43.5113563, lng: -79.6873432};
            var Oakvillemap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('oakville-map'), {
              zoom: 13,
              center: tmhOakville
            });
            var features = [
                {
                    position: tmhOakville,
                    type: 'one'
                }
            ];
             // Create markers.
            features.forEach(function(feature) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: feature.position,
                icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                map: Oakvillemap
              });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have a few more if blocks for various maps on certain pages but the syntax is the same for all of them. There is no geocoding involved, just a simple embed with custom markers.

Can anyone see a reason as to why this doesn't load in safari/iOS? Thanks

Comment: notice you using array.forEach, which is ECMAScript 5. And is relatively new. Possibly causing some compatiblity issues. But also when say 'breaks' - what EXACTLY does that mean? Did you check developer console?

Comment: @barryhunter by break I meant that it did not render or even run the JS on the container but I have solved my issue. Each if statement overwrote the initMap function and thus only the last map would load. Not sure why it didn't break in chrome but oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that each if statement overwrote the initMap function and thus only the last map would load. Still not sure why it would render fine in Chrome but not in Safari/iOS, the function would only render with the last if statement.